# Kibana issue connecting to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

Good day:

I've installed ElasticSearch (on Azure) and I"m trying to get my Kibana (local instance) connecting to my remote elastic instance however, I"m getting the following issue:

```
 [06:26:19.214] [warning][license][xpack] License information from the X-Pack plugin could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster. [invalid_index_name_exception] Invalid index name [_xpack], must not start with '_'., with { index_uuid="_na_" & index="_xpack" } :: {"path":"/_xpack","statusCode":400,"response":"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"invalid_index_name_exception\",\"reason\":\"Invalid index name [_xpack], must not start with '_'.\",\"index_uuid\":\"_na_\",\"index\":\"_xpack\"}],\"type\":\"invalid_index_name_exception\",\"reason\":\"Invalid index name [_xpack], must not start with '_'.\",\"index_uuid\":\"_na_\",\"index\":\"_xpack\"},\"status\":400}"}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like XPack is not installed on your ES server, while it is on your local Kibana instance

Comment: @Val is it possible to remove it from Kibana instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like XPack is not installed on your ES server, while it is on your local Kibana instance.

You can either install XPack on ES

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
```

or remove it from Kibana

```
bin/kibana-plugin remove x-pack
```

Comment: uninstall x-pack on windows gives `C:\Program Files\kibana\bin>kibana-plugin.bat remove x-pack
Unable to remove plugin because of error: "You are using the standard distrbution of Kibana.  Please install the OSS-only distribution to remove X-Pack features."`

Comment: ok that's because you didn't install the open-source version but the standard one. You should install this one instead: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-oss-6.3.2-windows-x86_64.zip and it won't have XPack in it.